# Force charset to generate SHA-256 in PHP

Tags: php, hash, encoding, character-encoding, sha256

I'm trying to generate a SHA-256 hex in PHP with ISO-8859-1 encoding, but did not find a way to do it.

Here's the "test case" (hardcoded) that I'm trying to complete:

```
function getHash($str) {
    return hash('sha256', $str);
}

$str1 = "Luiz";
$result1 = getHash($str1);
$expect1 = '0dd0029404cbe8bbad2cd84ec0f5089e4ca29d46719323b15595ffa765a88ffe';
$success1 = $result1 == $expect1 ? 'true' : 'false';

$str2 = "Luíz";
$result2 = getHash($str2);
$expect2 = '7e957af88c30f35d2fa32d6dd1c9931d3bb8a52b798277bfcbe06736f03d6828';
$success2 = $result2 == $expect2 ? 'true' : 'false';

echo "Test 1: ".$str1."<br/>";
echo "Result should be: ".$expect1."<br/>";
echo "Result is: ".$result1."<br/>";
echo "Success? ".$success1;

echo "<br/><br/><br/>";

echo "Test 2: ".$str2."<br/>";
echo "Result should be: ".$expect2."<br/>";
echo "Result is: ".$result2."<br/>";
echo "Success? ".$success2;
```

The first test case works just fine, but the second one fails (because of the encoding).

I've tried everything that I could... `pack`, `unpack`, `bin2Hex`, `mb_convert_encoding`... Nothing worked.

The reason I'm trying to do this is to integrate with a third-party product, that expects a SHA-256 hash in ISO-8859-1.

Their example, in Java, goes like this:

```
public class TokenGenerator {
    private static String getSha256Hash(final String x) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = md.digest(x.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
                if(hex.length() == 1) hexString.append('0');
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
            return hexString.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "EXAMPLE_STRING";
        System.out.println(getSha256Hash(str));
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example above, the Java version forces the hash to be in ISO-8859-1.
I believe that the PHP implementation only works with UTF-8, but I'm not certain.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: That's not hash's fault. it takes the exact byte sequence in the string you pass it, and hashes it. if you're getting a different hash value returned, then something is trashing the source code of your file so the `í` is being seen as something else.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought. But how can I force the PHP to see the character the expected way? Even if I force the encoding in the string (before the hash generation, with `mb_convert_encoding`), it does not work. In the Java example (that works like expected), it converts the byte array to the correct encoding before the hash generation. How could I do it?

Comment: it'd come down to more what your editor is doing with the file when the character's being inserted. could try `html_entities_decode('Lu&iacute;z', 'UTF-8')` or something.

Comment: I tried `utf8_decode` and it worked! Don't know why `mb_convert_encoding` didn't, thought. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks for the help ;D.